# Qt LanguageChange event - find out new language

Tags: c++, qt, multilingual, qevent

When I have `changeEvent(QEvent* event)` with receive type  `event->type() == QEvent::LanguageChange`, how can I get information about what the new language is in my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt don't have any object to represent application langugae. So you should implement it yorself.

Usually `changeEvent(QEvent* event)` with type `QEvent::LanguageChange` was caused by `installTranslator(QTranslator*)` so you should know witch langugae you loaded to translator and store it locally.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the translated string with its known translations:

```
void changeEvent(QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::LanguageChange) {
        QString translated = QCoreApplication::translate("some context", "Button");
        if (translated == "Button")
            // language is English
        else if (translated == "Кнопка")
            // language is Russian
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like workaround.. And won't work in case where I don't know how many languages I can have

Comment: This is so bad advice...